# DataTable.Rows.InsertAt won't accept new object[] where DataTable.Rows.Add does

Tags: c#, .net

I feel like I must not be doing something right here.  I have a `DataTable` and it's currently able to take my arguments using the DataTable.Rows.Add method, but when I use DataTable.Rows.InsertAt it throws an error

What I'm currently doing with no issues:

`dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { txtCompID.Text, scan(TrimStart('0'), txtEtaNum.Text, txtBinLocation.Text });`

What I want to do (so the insert happens at the top), which is throwing "Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'object[]' to 'System.Data.DataRow'"

`dt.Rows.InsertAt(new object[] { txtCompID.Text, scan.TrimStart('0'), txtEtaNum.Text, txtBinLocation.Text }, 0);`

Comment: Can you tell me why you want it inserted at the top? What's the driver for that?

Comment: @Blam, nope the reason it can't be done is because `InsertAt` requires a data row to be passed to it.

Comment: DataRow.Add has two Overloads one takes an object which you are using the other takes a DataRow. DataRow.InsertAt only has the DataRow Method.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input.  It was most definitely that InsertAt only has one overload.  I was able to create a new DataRow to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add row in dt that is of type of dt. You can use `dt.NewRow()` method to get the `row for dt`. You can do it this way.

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

dr[0] = "coldata1";
dr[1] = "coldata2";
dr[2] = "coldata3";
dr[3] = "coldata4";

dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Answer (score 1):

InsertAt doesn't support that. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.insertat.aspx). You need to construct a DataRow first and then you can insert it.